# Shopify + Rails: How do I create an app that adds methods to existing models (Product, etc)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am looking to create a Shopify app using Rails. However, I'm still not fully understanding how I would go about doing it. I created a private app, and hooked it up to my admin section using these directions: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app .

However, I don't really know where to go from here. When I start my Rails app server I get a homepage and I see recent products and orders. But... what now? Perhaps I am just unclear about what I could do with access of the `ShopifyAPI::Product` model and the such.

To provide a concrete example, I just installed the `Product Reviews` app in the Shopify app store. When I click it, I see product reviews, which I don't think is one of the original attributes/columns in the Product database. Also, in the themes it asked me to paste this line:

```
<div id="shopify-product-reviews" data-id="{{product.id}}">{{ product.metafields.spr.reviews }}</div>
```

How did this app add a  `spr` and `reviews` relationship to my product?  I know `metafields` already exists because of the API, but I would like to know how to add something like they did with `spr` and `reviews`

Comment: What is it you are trying to acheive using the API? If you could give us a concrete example of what you are trying to do with it, we can help more.

Comment: agreed. please specify are you trying to add scripts to the page or edit HTML through the theme?